# Memory leak when using TypeORM data source with Jest

Tags: jestjs, typeorm

I'm running into what seems like a memory leak when using a test data source in my Jest test suites. I've simplified it as best as possible down to the following:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

const testDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: ':memory:',
  dropSchema: true,
  entities: [],
  synchronize: true,
});

beforeAll(async () => {
  await testDataSource.initialize();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await testDataSource.dropDatabase();
  await testDataSource.destroy();
});

describe('example', () => {
  it('should add some things', async () => {
    expect(1 + 1).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

If I add 50 copies of this test file and track heap usage with the following, I see the heap size increasing for about 15 tests before running into an OOM.

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=512 node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage
```

Is there something more I can do to clean things up between tests?

I'm running Node v18.10.0, TypeORM 0.3.10, Jest 29.1.2, and SQLite3 5.1.2.

Example output:

```
% NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=512 node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage

 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-50.test.ts (171 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-30.test.ts (201 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-13.test.ts (225 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-27.test.ts (248 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-29.test.ts (272 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-38.test.ts (296 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-49.test.ts (319 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-31.test.ts (343 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-28.test.ts (367 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-48.test.ts (390 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-47.test.ts (414 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-42.test.ts (437 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-26.test.ts (460 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-12.test.ts (430 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-43.test.ts (449 MB heap size)
 PASS  test/typeorm/test-leak-46.test.ts (467 MB heap size)

 RUNS  test/typeorm/test-leak-41.test.ts

<--- Last few GCs --->

[61256:0x7f7cd124d000]    14700 ms: Scavenge 486.2 (521.1) -> 485.8 (522.1) MB, 2.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.574, current mu = 0.477) allocation failure;
[61256:0x7f7cd124d000]    14717 ms: Scavenge 487.4 (522.1) -> 486.9 (526.9) MB, 2.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.574, current mu = 0.477) allocation failure;
[61256:0x7f7cd124d000]    14837 ms: Mark-sweep 490.7 (527.1) -> 488.2 (529.9) MB, 88.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.546, current mu = 0.514) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: I'm getting `MaxListenersExceededWarning` when I run `--watch`. It's OK if I just run `npm test`. I'm using`beforeEach`/`afterEach` instead of `All`

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though this is related to the following known memory leak with Jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11956

Utilizing the `workerIdleMemoryLimit` configuration allowed our tests to pass.